# Add parentheses around numbers

Tags: text-processing

I have a file filled with numbers:

```
1 6 8 9 10 11
```

I want to enclose each number in parentheses so basically have the final output as:

```
(1) (6) (8) (9) (10) (11)
```

and so on.

Comment: Hi @Saiiiiaaafff. Welcome to unix.stackexchange.com. Just to make things clear: Your question have some formating issues and i have to ask. Is there a newline after each number, or you want to format them "inline" as it is right now?

Answer (score 3):

Try `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[0-9]\+/(&)/g' file.txt
```

In this `sed` substitution, we are substituting `[0-9]\+` i.e. successive digits with `(&)` i.e. parentheses around the matched digits. `g` means this replacement will take place for all matched patterns, otherwise it will only replace the first match.

After operation the modified file will be `file.txt` and the original file will be kept as `file.txt.bak`. Its a good practice to take backup of the original file, if you don't want to take backup just use:

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\+/(&)/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Note that the suffix `.bak` after the `-i` (modify file "in place") flag is optional. If you do not intend to keep a backup of the original file, it can be omitted: `sed -i 's/[0-9]*/(&)/g' file.txt`

Comment: It should actually be `[0-9]\+`. `[0-9]*` would match all the empty strings (places before and after any non-digit) in the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using Awk to only capture digits (will not print empty lines):

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /[[:digit:]]/) $i="("$i")"} NF{print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xargs printf '(%d) ' <infile
```

Would work to get output like your example in the question from any series of of numbers under 20 or so digits a piece separated by one or more whites spaces per.